# Chromium in 10.04 only showing blank pages

Tags: chromium, browser

I have a problem in Ubuntu 10.04...all pages with Chromium showed blank.

The first time I've noticed this problem was with Google Chrome, and because of that I've uninstalled and installed Chromium.

After seeing some threads in Google Groups some of the users said that it maybe some malware.

Because of that runned chkrootkit and rkhunter and nothing popped up, besides of this:

eth1: PACKET SNIFFER(/sbin/wpa_supplicant[1237], /sbin/dhclient3[3964])
virbr0: not promisc and no packet sniffer sockets

It's problematic? Can't tell...

Could anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).